# JS yield* equivalent for async generator

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, yield

I'm writing a recursive async generator function, but came to realize, I don't know the syntax for `yield*` when working with an async generator function.

That is, in a standard generator function, I can `yield*` (yield all) from another generator:

```
function* A() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}
function* B() {
    yield* A();
    yield* A();
}

[...B()] // === [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

But when working with an async generator, how do I yield all?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, maybe a dumb question (although [MDN doesn't seem to specify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) but [the specification does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)).
Just tried, and `yield*` works fine in both synchronous *and* asynchronous generators:

```js
async function* A() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}
async function* B() {
    // works fine
    yield* A();
    yield* A();
}

await (async() => {
    let arr = [];
    for await (let n of B()) {
        arr.push(n);
    }
    return arr;
})(); // Promise -> [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```